# How to edit .FRT report files

Tags: report, foxpro

I would like to edit a C legacy app.
So, I have to edit a static line in one of reports, not input related data.
Data: Info in report is outdated and has to be changed

I have no source to rebuild it, so i tried basically to open the report file (.FRT/.FRX)
Searched the line, edited/ saved, but the actual changes do not apply in app.

Comment: FRT/FRX files are basically FoxPro DBF files. If you don't have FoxPro, you can use ODBC to change them. The report might be embedded in the application. In this case it's of no use to change the external file.